# using Jenkins pipelines, call a parametrized job from another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs. Both are piplines. One is parametrized, the other is not.

I want to call the parametrized job from within the other job.

- JobA
- JobB

JobB's script

```
parameters {
   string(name: 'Directory')
}
.... do something...
```

JobA's script

```
call JobB("some/directory")    <-- how to do that?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call as below -
`steps {
   build job: 'job_name', parameters: [string(name: 'name', value: 'value')]
}`